# How can I do big parentheses and \\?

Tags: equations

I want a result like this picture, but when I write it, the parentheses remain small and I cannot divide the formula into two and write it on the bottom line. If you help me ı thank you.

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
{{P}_{d}}(\gamma )=Q\left( \frac{{{Q}^{-1}}({{P}_{fa,t\arg et}})\sqrt{2N}-N\gamma }{\sqrt{2N}(1+\gamma )} \right) \\ 
\simeq Q({{Q}^{-1}}({{P}_{fa,target}})-\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\gamma ) \\ 
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Where is the left/right in the second row? Additionally you cannot break the line in equation you need align instead

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

To break the equation in two lines one option is `align` from `amsmath` package, as daleif sais in the comments. Then the size of the parentheses can be chosen with the desired fixed size:

```
\[\Biggl( \biggl (\Bigl( \bigl( \times \bigr) \Bigr) \biggr) \Biggr)\]
```

or with adjustable size (as in you first line):

```
\[\left( x \right)\quad\left( \frac{x}{y} \right)\]
```

Your equation could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage   {amsmath} % for align

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{6} % just for this example

\begin{align}
P_{\textup{d}}^{\textup{CED}}(\gamma) & =\mathcal{Q}\left( \frac{\mathcal{Q}^{-1}(P_{\textup{fa,target}}^{\textup{CED}})\sqrt{2N}-N\gamma}{\sqrt{2N}(1+\gamma)} \right)\notag\\
& \simeq \mathcal{Q}\left(\mathcal{Q}^{-1}(P_{\textup{fa,target}}^{\textup{CED}})-\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\gamma\right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Writing `_\text{fa,target}` is to flirt with trouble. `_{\textup{fa,target}}` would be safer.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for the tip. Edited!!

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
\begin{align}
{{P}_{d}}(\gamma )&=\mathcal Q\left( \frac{{{\mathcal Q}^{-1}}({P}_{\mathrm{fa},\mathrm{target}}^{\mathrm{CED}})\sqrt{2N}-N\gamma }{\sqrt{2N}(1+\gamma )} \right)\nonumber \\ 
&\simeq\mathcal Q\left({{\mathcal Q}^{-1}}({P}_{\mathrm{fa},\mathrm{target}}^{\mathrm{CED}})-\sqrt{\frac{N}{2}}\gamma \right)
\end{align}
```

instead. You should get this:

[image]